# why is my min function printing multiple values, shouldn't it print only one?

Tags: python, nested-lists, min

the problem I'm having is trying to get my `min()` function to print only the lowest values and then print the nested list that contains that lowest value. I know that `min()` should only produce one number but I keep getting multiple values that include the lowest.

```
matches = [
  ['Mariam Cox', 'Ely', '67'], 
  ['Mikayla Bonner', 'Ely', '66'], 
  ['Jaquelyn Bowman', 'Ely', '68'], 
  ['Henry Dickson', 'Ely', '62'], 
  ['Daniel Ashley', 'Ely', '65'], 
  ['Michelle Wilkerson', 'Ely', '64'], 
  ['Shannon Hogan', 'Ely', '84'], 
  ['Justine Carrillo', 'Ely', '71'], 
  ['Dustin Lara', 'Ely', '62'], 
  ['Gabriel Graham', 'Ely', '81']
]      (name, city, height)
```

I'm trying to find the `min()` height, `'62'`, and print all their information. I'm just struggling to understand why I keep getting multiple values

```
search_city = input('what city are we looking for:')
indexes = [i for i, (name, city, height) in enumerate(data) if city == search_city]
matches = [el for el in data if el[1] == search_city]

Zs = []
for m in matches:
    Zs.append(float(m[2]))
    minimum_height = min(Zs)
    print(minimum_height)
```

this is what I have for finding the lowest values. the top is not quite related, more or less the bottom.
I get this output:

```
67.0
66.0
66.0
62.0
62.0
62.0
62.0
62.0
62.0
62.0
```

so the 62 is coming out but also with all other values.

Comment: Take the `print()` statement out of the loop if you only want to print the final result.

Comment: The assignment to `minimum_height` should also not be in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for m in matches:
>     Zs.append(float(m[2]))
>     minimum_height = min(Zs)
>     print(minimum_height)
> ```

It's printed multiple times because your print is in the loop and is therefore executed multiple times.

I would suggest you get the minimum height this way:

```
minimum_height = min(int(x[2]) for x in matches)
```

If you want to print every element in `matches` that has that minimum height you might then:

```
for x in matches:
  if int(x[2]) == minimum_height:
    print(x)
```

Or if you only want the *first* match with the minimum height:

```
>>> min(matches, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))
['Henry Dickson', 'Ely', '62']
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chris already explain the reason and showed a clean way of doing it. If you want to do that in one pass you can try the following:

```py
matches = [
    ["Mariam Cox", "Ely", "67"],
    ["Mikayla Bonner", "Ely", "66"],
    ["Jaquelyn Bowman", "Ely", "68"],
    ["Henry Dickson", "Ely", "62"],
    ["Daniel Ashley", "Ely", "65"],
    ["Michelle Wilkerson", "Ely", "64"],
    ["Shannon Hogan", "Ely", "84"],
    ["Justine Carrillo", "Ely", "71"],
    ["Dustin Lara", "Ely", "62"],
    ["Gabriel Graham", "Ely", "81"],
]

min_ = float("inf")
res = []
for lst in matches:
    n = int(lst[2])
    if n < min_:
        min_ = n
        res = [lst]
    elif n == min_:
        res.append(lst)

print(res)
```

output:

```
[['Henry Dickson', 'Ely', '62'], ['Dustin Lara', 'Ely', '62']]
```